# On scaling tags in a tag cloud

Tags: language-agnostic, user-interface, rendering, tagging, tag-cloud

I am implementing a tag cloud on a mobile device. The details of data-model etc, are not particularly important here. My question is about the scaling of tags:

**What is the 'best' expression to map tag frequency to font size?**

I have looked at [this post](http://blogs.dekoh.com/dev/2007/10/29/choosing-a-good-font-size-variation-algorithm-for-your-tag-cloud/) discussing linear and logarithmic scaling and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613274/fitting-tag-cloud-to-available-space/672802#672802) from Adrian Kuhn sketch of a polynomial approach for inspiration. However, I seem to remember a post some place on the interwebs with a lot more exploration on this issue.

I have also found some "[best practices](http://www.joelamantia.com/tag-clouds/10-best-practices-for-displaying-tag-clouds)" on a blog, though am unsure of the providence of the best practices. These make no comment on frequency scaling.

What alternatives do I have for tag scaling, and which is the preferred/standard method? I am also considering minimum fontsizes, maximum number of tags, colors, etc.

Edit: As per the discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240263/preferable-tag-cloud-visualization-formats), I am interested in the "standard" tagcloud, with font size variations.

Comment: Er, check out the right-hand column of this site - order by number of instances descending, with number to the right. Works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked on a small tag cloud project last year, in which I used something along the lines of

> β = (int) (((maxθ – minθ) x ω) + minθ + 0.5)

where ω is a weighting previously calculated according to some metric (in your case font frequency), minθ and maxθ are lower and upper bounds, and β is the final value. This can be applied to any visual characteristic (font size, colour, weight if supported, etc.).

I found that linear and logarithmic scaling tended to dependant on data set distribution. In data sets with prominent outliers I found tanh was useful for 'smoothing' the resulting values.

Comment: This is the linear scaling I eventually went with. Great idea re: tanh, I'll look at that further.

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent discussion in [this pdf](http://files.blog-city.com/files/J05/88284/b/insearchofperfecttagcloud.pdf), which discusses scaling, clustering, and truncating on the tags to display.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found works nicely is as follows

`font_size = (max_font_size - min_font_size) * (Math.sin(1.5*(X)) + minsize`

where X is the normalized value you wish to map onto font size

`X = (this_value-min_value)/(max_value-min_value)`

this increases size differential for the lower 3 quartiles of the range, such as to minimize the effect of high outliers